# Show 'no more posts' when loaded all posts using ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Below is the javascript part and load more button which I am using to load more posts from database it works fine I want to show a 'no more posts' message when all posts have been loaded but do not know how to do that exactly. Hope you guys can help.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'mload_more.php',
            data:'id='+ID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.posts').append(html);
           }
        });        
    });
});
</script>

<div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main<?php echo $ID; ?>">
    <span id="<?php echo $ID; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">
        Show more
    </span>
    <span class="loding" style="display: none;">
        <span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try passing html from mload_more as json data. One with content, other with option for show more / no more posts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gayan just gave me a start and rest was not much difficult.

```
<?php   
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
}
}
else {
echo $er = "No more posts to load";
}  
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var er = "<?php echo $er; ?>";
if(er!=''){
$("er").show();
$('.show_more').hide();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Within mload_more.php file check the number of returned rows greater than zero. It would be as following code.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //display data
    }
} else {
    echo "No more posts to load";
}
```